# Are iOS GM seeds the same as the final product?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I would like to update my iPad to iOS 4.2 (I am a registered developer) but I wanted to wait until the final release. Is the GM the final release, or are changes made in the final version after the GM?

Comment: Why is this question subjective? I don't understand the vote to close at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. They can be made, but most of the time the GM is gonna be the final version.